# QGIS cannot see rasters in postgres10 / postgis 2.4

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am running a postgis-enabled postgres database. I recently did an upgrade from 9.6 to postgres10 using postgis 2.4 on both databases. all my vectordatasets still works fine, but I had a dtm as a raster data set in the data base that now shows up in without geometry. I have also tried to reimport the dtm, but to no avail. Is there anything special I need to do to activate the raster support? Raster calculations seems to work fine in postgres, so the problem must be somewhere in the interface between postgres and qgis. I am using qgis 2.14.11 and the nightly build of 2.99 - both with the same result.